# An sshpass bash script that takes a file as input for servernames/ips and user input for password

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

Why in my bash script does the following statment return a space between root@hostname.local and the colon

```
    hostline2='root@'$i':'
```

IE: root@192.168.0.1 :

instead of root@192.168.0.1:

the trailing space behind the ip address is ruining an scp statement I'm trying to pass this to in my script.

for example I'm trying to do this

```
    sshpass -e scp -o StrictHostKeychecking=no $2 $hostline2$2
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, which would lead me to believe the space is in `$i` itself. Can you check for that?

Comment: no it shouldn't. Did you try echoing out $i?

Comment: The space *is* in `$i`. How is the value of `$i` set? Incidentally, you rarely want to expand a parameter outside of quotes; use `hostline2="root@$i:"` instead.